# VB.NET - Extend property in child class

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, properties, expand

Maybe somebody can help me out please, i can imagine it is a common need:
I have a base and a child class. The base class has a property named "hello". Now I need to add extended functionality in the property Set of the child - How can I achive that?

A code sample for further explanation:

**Base Class:**

```
Public MustInherit Class Base

    Private pHello as String = ""

    Public Property Hello As String
        Get
            Return pHello
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
                pHello = value
                'DoSomethingInBaseClass()
                MsgBox "BaseClass calling!" 'Just for testing
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

**Child Class**

```
Public Class Child
    Inherits Base

    Public Property Hello As String
        Get
            Return MyBase.Hello
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
                'DoSomethingInCHILDClass()
                MsgBox "ChildClass calling!" 'Just for testing
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

**Property Set in Main**

```
Public Class Main

    Public Sub DoIt()
        Dim InstChild as new Child
        InstChild.Hello = "test"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Basically what i want is, when setting the property, that I first get the Child MessageBox and then the Base MessageBox.

Sure I need to add a keyword in the Property definition(s).
I played around with Shadows and Overrides, but either I get only the Child or only the Base Message.

Is there a way to get both?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend doing the work in an overridable function. This way you can have the child class do its work then call MyBase.overriddenFunction().

For example:

**Base Class**

```
Public MustInherit Class Base

    Private pHello as String = ""

    Public Property Hello As String
        Get
            Return pHello
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
                pHello = value
                doSomething()
                MsgBox "BaseClass calling!" 'Just for testing
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Overridable Sub doSomething()
        'Do base class stuff
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Child Class**

```
Public Class Child
    Inherits Base

    Public Property Hello As String
        Get
            Return MyBase.Hello
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
                doSomething()
                MsgBox "ChildClass calling!" 'Just for testing
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Overrides Sub doSomething()
        'Do child class stuff
        MyBase.doSomething()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
This works fine! 
I thought there would be a cleaner solution, but at least with this workaround is functionally.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the child class. Instead of returning `myBase.hello` just return `Me.hello`. 
because at first `me.hello` of the child class will be equal to the `hello` of the `base class`. So when you override the property, at the base class it will remain the same, and it will only change on the child class.
 so in order to get both of you should call: `Base.Hello.get()` and `Child.Hello.get()`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!
I hope I understood you right, but changing it to me.hello in the Child Get causes a recursive call.
Anyway, my problem is in the Set. I want that first the Child Set is called, then the Base Set.
Unfortunately I can't upvote you, my rep is too low :(